# How to make Apple X11 the default X11 app?

Tags: macos, x11, osx-mavericks

I have OS X mavericks. Yesterday I installed xQuartz but then decided that I want to make Apple's X11 the default X11 eninronemnt. I check the website of [xQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X11-UsersFAQ) where it said I should run the following commands:

```
(XQuartz.app) launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist
(Apple's X11.app) launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.x.startx.plist
(MacPorts' X11.app) launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.macports.startx.plist
```

The first command runs correctly, but the last two gives me that there's no such file or directory error. So now how can I make Apple's X11 the default?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's X11 is no longer supported in Mavericks. You can run it but it may not work. Only xQuartz has been updated and supported up to Mavericks. The old apple's x11 no longer comes with the operating system. As a matter of fact, you can't install it unless you have access to an old install disk or obtain the file from someone else. Apple even suggests to install XQuartz [instead](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5293). So unless you managed to install apple's old x11 by hand, that file shouldn't exist.

Comment: May I ask, what is exactly XQuartz? I found out somewhere that it is a windowing system? Does it run continuously? What window system does Mavericks use and does Xquartz replace it?

I am sorry if the questions are stupid, I just haven't been able to find much information about xquartz

Comment: This answer is not right, because questioner like to get back to default/native display manager (just like a clear installed Mavericks)

Answer (score 1):

[From XQuartz's faq:](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X11-UsersFAQ#UninstallSnowLeopardorLater)

> **Uninstall (Snow Leopard or Later)**
>
> XQuartz does not replace the system X11 on Snow Leopard, so you can go
>   back to the Apple-provided X11.app rather easily. Just launch X11.app
>   rather than XQuartz.app to get the older server. If you want to make
>   Apple's X11.app the default server (owning the launchd $DISPLAY
>   socket), then you should disable the
>   org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist as described in the first
>   question. After logging out and back in, Apple's X11.app will be
>   default. If you still want to remove XQuartz.app from your system, you
>   can do that with these two steps:
>
> ```
> launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist
> sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macosforge.xquartz.privileged_startx.plist
> sudo rm -rf /opt/X11* /Library/Launch*/org.macosforge.xquartz.* /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app /etc/*paths.d/*XQuartz
> sudo pkgutil --forget org.macosforge.xquartz.pkg
> ```
>
> Please file a bug report
>   to let us know why you reverted to the system X11.app, so we can
>   address the problem in a future release.